# How to stop rounding in Excel (SUM function)?

Tags: excel, mongodb, sum

I have the same set of data stored in MongoDB and Excel, but when I'm selecting sum from MongoDB, it's 3219537834.801277, and Excel returns 3219537834.80127. Cell format is "0.00000000000000000000" (maximal amount of decimal places). How do I disable rounding in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a rounding or format issue.  It is a precision issue.  Because of the IEEE format that Excel uses for floating point numbers, there is a limit to precision.  See:

[Floating Point Issues](https://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be a provisional solution, for short sheets:

1. Change the cells you want to text-formatted cells.
2. If doesn't work, I can solve it by clicking the check icon (with the "insert" tooltip) besides the formula bar. It still invoke an excel advert, but it solves the problem basically.